# Determine which task has completed

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I am trying to determine which Task has completed in my Task Array so that I might take some further action.  All of my tasks are starting with some initial data.  They might not necessarily complete, as an exception might be thrown so I can't rely on a return code.

I can't determine how to attach a unique identifier to the Task.  I considered keeping a table somewhere of the TaskID but that seems inefficient and I have read that Task ID is not unique which will require some additional management.  I have also read about attaching custom properties, but have not ventured down that path, and finally there is some suggestion that I could use the AsyncState property to put my object, but the .Net documentation doesn't seem to align with this.

Some basic code below of the issue I am trying to resolve.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task SomethingAsync(string theValue)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        Console.WriteLine(theValue);
        // Do a CPU bound activity
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            ;
    }
    static void AwaitAllTasks(List<Task> tasksList)
    {
        /// Use a wait any loop to find any tasks that have completed
        /// Warning: this is O(N2) and will not scale for thousands of tasks

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (tasksList.Count > 0)
            {
                var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasksList);
                tasksList.Remove(t);
                Console.WriteLine("One of the tasks completed.  Was it Task 1 or Task 2? Task ID: {0}", t.Id);
            }
        }
        /// Blocking on the main thread??? Is this the right way to do this?
        /// If we don't block on the main thread the application exits....
        ).Wait();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

        taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => SomethingAsync("Task 1")));
        taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => SomethingAsync("Task 2")));

        AwaitAllTasks(taskList);
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know the index of the completed task in the array of tasks? Or do you want to associate each task with some kind of key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is very similar to what's proposed in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/start-multiple-async-tasks-and-process-them-as-they-complete#complete-example). The main difference is that they use generically typed tasks so they can await them to see the data returned.

Applying the patterns from that article to your code would look something like this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var taskList = new[] { "Task 1", "Task 2" }
    .Select(SomethingAsync)
    .ToList();
    await AwaitAllTasks(taskList);
    Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
}

static async Task AwaitAllTasks(List<Task<string>> tasksList)
{
    /// Use a wait any loop to find any tasks that have completed
    /// Warning: this is O(N2) and will not scale for thousands of tasks
    while (tasksList.Count > 0)
    {
        var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasksList);
        tasksList.Remove(t);
        var theValue = await t;
        Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} completed.", theValue);
    }
}

static async Task<string> SomethingAsync(string theValue)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine(theValue);
    // Do a CPU bound activity
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        ;
    return theValue;
}
```

A couple of notes:
- There's no need for `AwaitAllTasks` to do `Task.Run()`. It's not CPU-intensive.
- C# now allows you to have an async Main method, so you can `await` instead of blocking on the main thread.

Regarding this:

> They might not necessarily complete, as an exception might be thrown so I can't rely on a return code.

If an exception is thrown, the task will *complete*, but trying to `await` it will cause an exception to be thrown. So you might want to add a try/catch around the `await t`.

If it's possible that the task might literally never complete, you may want to use a cancellation token to avoid waiting for them indefinitely.

### Update

If you need to track specific information related to the task regardless of whether the task is successful, you'll need to use an appropriate collection, like a Dictionary, to maintain that correlation. For example:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var tasks = new[] { "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3" }
    .ToDictionary(name => SomethingAsync(name));
    await AwaitAllTasks(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
}

static async Task AwaitAllTasks(IDictionary<Task, string> tasks)
{
    /// Use a wait any loop to find any tasks that have completed
    /// Warning: this is O(N2) and will not scale for thousands of tasks
    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasks.Keys);
        var theValue = tasks[t];
        tasks.Remove(t);
        try
        {
            await t;
            Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} completed.");
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} had a failure.");
        }
    }
}

static async Task SomethingAsync(string theValue)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    Console.WriteLine(theValue);
    if(theValue == "Task 2"){
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Foo");
    }
    // Do a CPU bound activity
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        ;
}
```

### Update 2

Another option is to avoid having a separate method for awaiting all the tasks individually, and just treat the action you want to take after each task as a continuation of each task. I usually find it best to think of a group of async tasks as a kind of data flow, where the result of each one can be passed into another operation, LINQ-style, until you're ready to bring their results all back together again.

```
async Task Main()
{
    var continuations = 
        from theValue in new[] { "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3" }
            // AsParallel() ensures the tasks are _begun_ in a multithreaded way.
            // Use it if SomethingAsync() might block the CPU for a while before 
            // yielding the thread.
            .AsParallel()
        let task = SomethingAsync(theValue)
        select ContinueSomething(task, theValue);
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(continuations);
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some tasks failed");
    }
}

static async Task ContinueSomething(Task somethingTask, string theValue)
{
    try
    {
        await somethingTask;
        Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} completed.");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} had a failure.");
    }
}
```

And of course, `async/await` is mostly syntactic sugar for things you could do otherwise. `ContinueSomething()` could be rewritten as:

```
static Task ContinueSomething(Task somethingTask, string theValue)
{
    return somethingTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsFaulted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} had a failure.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} completed.");
        }
    });
}
```

Or you could even inline it into your original LINQ statement:

```
async Task Main()
{
    var continuations = 
        from theValue in new[] { "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3" }.AsParallel()
        let task = SomethingAsync(theValue)
        select task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.IsFaulted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} had a failure.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} completed.");
            }
        });
    await Task.WhenAll(continuations);
}
```

Of course, this all assumes your operations are inherently asynchronous. If your actual use case looks anything like the one you've posted, with almost entirely CPU-bound activity, you may want to skip the `async` stuff and just let `Parallel.ForEach()` take care of the parallelism for you:

```
void Main()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(new[] { "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3" }, theValue =>
    {
        try
        {
            SomethingAsync(theValue);
            Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} completed.");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{theValue} had a failure.");
        }
    });
    Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
}

static void SomethingAsync(string theValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine(theValue);
    if (theValue == "Task 2")
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Foo");
    }
    // Do a CPU bound activity
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        ;
}
```

Point being: there are a lot of different ways to do the sort of thing you're trying to do, and which one is best will depend somewhat on specifics.

Comment: thanks.  That was really helpful.  Now if the Task has thrown an exception, then as you say, if I await it in the WhenAny loop, it throws another exception and I can't get the string back.  Do I need to throw a custom exception from within the task and bubble up the string with the original exception as an inner?  Or is there a cleaner way?  Thanks.

Comment: A note about the note. `Task.Run` is not necessarily for CPU intensive jobs. Given an async delegate as argument, the `Task.Run` will utilize a thread-pool thread to just start the task, which is normally a minuscule amount of work measured in μsec. In the abnormal case where *starting* the task happens to be CPU intensive, offloading this CPU intensive work to a thread-pool thread can be desirable, especially if we are talking about event handlers of UI applications.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: That's an interesting caveat, but I don't think it really applies to `AwaitAllTasks`. We know that nothing leading up to the first `await` in `AwaitAllTasks` is CPU-intensive. And if any of the given Tasks took CPU time to _start,_ that effort would have been accomplished before `AwaitAllTasks` was called. The responsibility to avoid getting CPU-bound would lie with the code starting those tasks. Depending on the environment, it might be appropriate for that code to use `Task.Run()` or `.AsParallel()` or `await Task.Yield()` to ensure starting those tasks won't block the UI.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior you are right. In this specific case the `Task.Run` is redundant. It's not harmful, but I agree that it should be removed since it offers no value here.

Comment: @RowanSmith: I spent some more time thinking about what you're trying to do here, and came up with a few more options that I think would be more elegant than what I started with. Check out Update 2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, and compare the few differences between your code and this code:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task<string> SomethingAsync(string theValue)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        Console.WriteLine(theValue);
        // Do a CPU bound activity
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            ;
        return theValue;
    }
    static void AwaitAllTasks(List<Task> tasksList)
    {
        /// Use a wait any loop to find any tasks that have completed
        /// Warning: this is O(N2) and will not scale for thousands of tasks
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (tasksList.Count > 0)
            {
                var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasksList);
                tasksList.Remove(t);
                //Console.WriteLine("One of the tasks completed.  Was it Task 1 or Task 2? Task ID: {0}", t.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("One of the tasks completed.  It was {0}", ((Task<string>)t).Result);
            }
        }
        /// Blocking on the main thread??? Is this the right way to do this?
        /// If we don't block on the main thread the application exits....
        ).Wait();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

        taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => SomethingAsync("Task 1")));
        taskList.Add(Task.Run(() => SomethingAsync("Task 2")));

        AwaitAllTasks(taskList);
        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
var query =
    from n in Observable.Range(1, 2)
    let text = $"Task {n}"
    from r in Observable.FromAsync(() => Task.Run(() => SomethingAsync(text)))
    select text;

var subscription =
    query
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .Subscribe(z =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{z.x} finished in position {z.n}");
        });
```

That produces output like this:

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 2 finished in position 0
Task 1 finished in position 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetAccountsByAPI());
var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetAccountsByAPI());
var taskList = new List<Task>()
{
    task1, task2 //Add other tasks
};

#region You can run this part iteratively
var completedTask = Task.WhenAny(taskList).Result;
taskList.Remove(completedTask);
#endRegion
```